# Writing nested promise javascript es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

does anyone have any guides or tips on how to write a nested promises?

I am trying to turn the following nested `for loop` into a promise:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


for (i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {

  for (j = i + 1; j < arr.length ; j++) {

      // call another asynchronous function

  }

}
```

I thought about doing `Promise.all`, but the iterator in the inside `for` loop starts at `j = i + 1` so I wasn't sure how to handle this with `Promise.all`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example?  I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Perhaps using generators will help? This explains it quite well: https://davidwalsh.name/async-generators

Comment: `Promise.all` takes an array. It doesn't matter how many promises it contains, or how that number relates to your iteration counter. Do you know how to use it with non-nested loops?

Comment: @Thijs No. If at all, `async`/`await` syntax will, but that leads to sequential instead of concurrent execution.

Comment: @Bergi I'd also point out that the Promise it returns is related only to the Array as it was passed.  In other words, you can't push to the array you gave Promise.all while it is waiting and expect it to wait on the additional, pushed Promise.  I have seen some trip on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push them into an array

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const promises = []
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
    promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 100, [i,j]);
    }));
  }
}
Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
  console.log(values);
});
```